# How receive Integer value in RestKit 0.20?

Tags: ios, mapping, restkit

I've rest Object as:

```
@interface VFEQuestionnaireRest : NSObject
    @property(copy ,nonatomic) NSNumber *iid;
    @property(copy, nonatomic)NSString *namePoll;
    @property(copy, nonatomic)NSSet *questions;
@end
```

and coming JSON as:

```
    {"questionnaire":[
      {"id":4,"namePoll":"questionario4","questions":              
         {"id":13,"idQuestionnaire":4,"nameQuestion":"costo?",
            "questionType":{"id":2,"nameType":"WHOLE"}}}]}
```

The value "iid" is  always "0", and namePoll have its correct value.
 How can mapping int value from JSON to `NSNumber` objC?

-

```
RKObjectMapping *questionnaireMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[VFEQuestionnaireRest class]];
    [questionnaireMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
     @{@"iid":@"id",
    @"namePoll":@"namePoll"
     }];
[questionnaireMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"questions" toKeyPath:@"questions"  withMapping:questionMapping]];
```

Comment: Maybe by reading the documentation? `NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:42];`

Comment: Sorry , where I can put this "magical" sentences?I refer to RestKit RKObjectMapping...

Comment: first you want to figure out **where** you want to perform that int-to-NSNumber conversion, since this snippet does that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your mapping is incorrect. It should be source -> destination and not the other way around:

```
RKObjectMapping *questionnaireMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[VFEQuestionnaireRest class]];
[questionnaireMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:
   @{ @"id":@"iid",
   @"namePoll":@"namePoll" }];
```

Restkit performs int -> NSNumber conversion automatically.